# PHP PDO fetching an object

Tags: php, class, object, pdo, fetch

I'm trying to fetch a User object and return it.

```
<?php
class User {
    private $id;
    private $username;
    private $email;

    function __construct($id, $username, $email) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    function getUsername() {
        return $this->username;
    }

    function getEmail() {
        return $this->email;
    }   
}
```

This works, but seems inefficient (is it?):

```
$user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$result = new User($user['id'], $user['username'], $user['email']);
return $result;
```

This gives me errors:

```
$user = $stmt->fetchObject('User');
return $user;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `PDO::FETCH_OBJ`

Comment: What's the 'error? PDO won't return a `User` object, it will return the data as an object, that is, with each column name as a member and value set to the data value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first method is how it's done. If you want a User object, you have to create it. I don't see any reason it would be inefficient.